# Referenciar variável da classe principal, em uma @Override

Tags: java, android

Podemos referenciar uma variável da classe principal, por exemplo dentro do método `onCreate` das 2 formas (com ou sem o `this`):

```
public class NovoRegistro extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView data, horario;
int dia, mes, ano;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo_registro);

       this.data = findViewById(R.id.tvwData);
       horario = findViewById(R.id.tvwHorario);
   }
}
```

Mas se eu estou dentro de um método sobrescrito de outra classe, não posso usar o `this`, se não estaria puxando da classe principal do método.

Exemplo:

```
public void datePicker(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int ano, int mes, int dia) {
                mes = mes + 1;
                String dataSelecionada = (dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano);
                data.setText(dataSelecionada);
            }
        }, ano, mes, dia);
        dp.show();
    }
```

No exemplo acima, o método `onDateSet` está me retornando `ano, mes, dia` exatamente como na minha classe principal.

**Qual seria a melhor forma para setar as propriedades `ano, mes, dia` da minha classe principal, com as propriedades do método ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema aqui é as variáveis do método terem o mesmo nome dos campos da Activity.
Use `NovoRegistro.this` para aceder ao objecto NovoRegistro(a sua activity):

```
NovoRegistro.this.ano = ano;
NovoRegistro.this.mes = mes;
NovoRegistro.this.dia = dia;
```

`this` é uma palavra reservada que, neste contexto, é uma referência ao objecto actual. É como se fosse uma variável(campo) que guarda o objecto actual.
Para referenciá-la numa *inner class* deverá incluir o nome da *outer class*: `NomeDaOuterClasse.this`.

Como `NovoResgisto.this` representa a instância de NovoRegisto pode, através dela, aceder a todos os seus membros.

Comment: Grande professor ramaral ! Terei que deixar as propriedades como `static` nesse caso correto ? Tem alguma outra forma ou somente essa ?

Comment: Não, `NovoRegistro.this` representa a instância.

Comment: Muito bom !! Testado com o this, e realmente não precisa deixar as propriedades estáticas. Obrigado ! Abraço !

Comment: Outra forma seria NovoRegistro ter um método para "setar" esses atributos.